# shall we create feature file in codeception using BDD? or codeception will generate feature using cept file automatically?

Tags: codeception

In codeception we need to create feature file(scenario) using BDD or it will generate feature file(scenario) using cept file automatically?

Please tell me whether we need to create scenario in codeception to execute the script(testcase) or not?